# unable to run mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I keep getting the output failed i did `die()` right after my `$query` and got the desired result but after that nothing seems to work. Can somebody point out as to what I am doing wrong?

```
$query="UPDATE `u313495632_test`.`users` SET `firstname='$firstname',`surname`='$surname',`gender`='$gender' WHERE `users`.`id`='$user'";
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
    echo 'Profile Updated';                                 
} else {
    echo 'Failed';
}
```

Comment: FYI mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO. But this is not related to your problem

Comment: Yups its not but thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: replace `echo 'Failed';` with echo `mysql_error();`. It could give you a clue on what is wrong.

Comment: Besides that it is deprecated, your script is vulnerable for [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: `\`firstname=` should be `\`firstname\`=` You forgot a back tick after the field name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
 $query="UPDATE `u313495632_test`.`users` SET `firstname`='$firstname',`surname`='$surname',`gender`='$gender' WHERE `users`.`id`='$user'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
if (!$query_run) {
  echo 'Failed';
} else {
  echo 'Profile Updated';                                 
}
```

And You should use mysqli or PDO. Mysql is deprecated.

Comment: Apart from just posting code, please let the user know what he did wrong and why.

Comment: @RobQuist i agree with you

Comment: @haseeb Thanks for the code but may i know what i did wrong

Comment: Your if statement it was wrong. You wrote `if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) ` it is incorrect because you can't assign variables in if statement. Correct way would be to assign variable first and then check if the value is `true` or `false`. And also there was a mistake is your sql statement you were missing a \` sign after the `firstname`

Answer (score 1):

`firstname= should be `firstname`= You forgot a back tick after the field name.